# Python list formatting

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list that I read in from a file that looks like this:

```
D0 DA D7 00 D0 DA D7 00 
D0 DA D7 00 F0 DA D7 00 
F0 DA D7 00 D0 DA D7 00 
D0 DA D7 00 D2 DA 8E 00 
D2 DA 9D 00 D2 DA D9 00 
D2 DA AC 00 D2 DA E8 00 
D2 DA F7 00 D2 DA 06 00 
D2 DA 15 00 D2 DA 24 00 
D2 DA 33 00 D2 DA 42 00 
D2 DA 51 00 D2 DA 60 00 
D2 DA 6F 00 D2 DA CA 00 
D2 DA 7E 00 D2 DA BB 00 
D0 DA D7 FF FF FF FF FF
```

I am creating another list through reads to some hardware which looks like this:

```
 D0
 DA
 D7
 00
 DA
 .....
```

I want to format this list I am reading back into the one that looks like the one above. I don't want to create two lists where I read into one and then format and write to another. Is there some syntax that I can use to automatically read in values into the second list in the format of the first list?

```
for ii in xrange(0xC000,0xFFFF,2):  
    rv2.write('m75421_2', regname, ii)
    time.sleep(0.001)
    mem_value = rv2.read('m75421_2',ii)
    list2.append(mem_value) ----some syntax that I can add to this append here
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are these strings or just representation of binary data?

Comment: Is your first file, the one you want the data to look like, dynamic or does it always have 8 columns?

Comment: Is that first input block a file?? or a representation of a 2d array?

Comment: The first input is a file. Basically data at memory locations 0xC000 to 0xFFFF written to a text file. This file isn't dynamic.The syntax always remains the same i.e 8 columns.

Comment: @serendipity can you restate your question please? It would be nice to provide us with 2 variable containing the info you want to compare. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to format it, you can do this:

```
>>> data=['D0', 'DA', 'D7', '00', 'D0', 'DA', 'D7', '00', 'D0', 'DA', 'D7', '00', 'F0', 'DA', 'D7', '00', 'F0', 'DA', 'D7', '00', 'D0', 'DA', 'D7', '00', 'D0', 'DA', 'D7', '00', 'D2', 'DA', '8E', '00', 'D2', 'DA', '9D', '00', 'D2', 'DA', 'D9', '00', 'D2', 'DA', 'AC', '00', 'D2', 'DA', 'E8', '00', 'D2', 'DA', 'F7', '00', 'D2', 'DA', '06', '00', 'D2', 'DA', '15', '00', 'D2', 'DA', '24', '00', 'D2', 'DA', '33', '00', 'D2', 'DA', '42', '00', 'D2', 'DA', '51', '00', 'D2', 'DA', '60', '00', 'D2', 'DA', '6F', '00', 'D2', 'DA', 'CA', '00', 'D2', 'DA', '7E', '00', 'D2', 'DA', 'BB', '00', 'D0', 'DA', 'D7', 'FF', 'FF', 'FF', 'FF', 'FF']
>>> cols=8
>>> print '\n'.join(' '.join(data[i:i+cols]) for i in range(0,len(data),cols))
D0 DA D7 00 D0 DA D7 00
D0 DA D7 00 F0 DA D7 00
F0 DA D7 00 D0 DA D7 00
D0 DA D7 00 D2 DA 8E 00
D2 DA 9D 00 D2 DA D9 00
D2 DA AC 00 D2 DA E8 00
D2 DA F7 00 D2 DA 06 00
D2 DA 15 00 D2 DA 24 00
D2 DA 33 00 D2 DA 42 00
D2 DA 51 00 D2 DA 60 00
D2 DA 6F 00 D2 DA CA 00
D2 DA 7E 00 D2 DA BB 00
D0 DA D7 FF FF FF FF FF
```

Comment: instead of a print can I use an append statement because the ultimate goal is to compare list1 and list2 where list1 is a pre-existing file and list2 contains data that gets read in from the hardware.

Comment: If that works, yes. To the right of the `print` is just a string. Lists can hold strings.

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming the read is returning integers.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    '''group into sub-sequences of size n'''
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

def values(lo, hi, rv2, regname):
    '''yield memory values from lo to hi'''
    for ii in xrange(lo, hi, 2):  
        rv2.write('m75421_2', regname, ii)
        time.sleep(0.001)
        yield rv2.read('m75421_2', ii)

def fmt(line):
    '''format a line of integers as 2 digit hex with spaces'''
    return ' '.join(['%02x'] * len(line)) % line

map(fmt, grouper(values(0xC000, 0xFFFF, rv2, regname), 8, 0))
```

grouper from http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes

if the read is returning hex strings:

```
def fmt(line):
    '''format a line of 2 digit hex strings'''
    return ' '.join(map(lambda s: s.strip(), line))

map(fmt, grouper(values(0xC000, 0xFFFF, rv2, regname), 8, '--'))
```